# Error Function::flpar - Issue with output of DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, functions

I appologise for the confusing question, but I don't know enough Mathematica nomenclature to formulate it properly. My question is that when I do:

```
sol = DSolve[D[x[0][T[0], T[1]], T[0], T[0]]+\[Omega] ^2 x[0][T[0], T[1]]  == 0, x[0], {T[0], T[1]}]
```

I get

```
{{x[0]->Function[{T[0],T[1]},Cos[\[Omega] T[0]] Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1][T[1]]+Sin[\[Omega] T[0]] Subscript[\[ConstantC], 2][T[1]]]}}
```

First of all, this is a list containing a single list containing a single replace rule. Why return the output in such a convoluted way?

Secondly, I want to get this into a usable format for further computations, i.e., I want

```
Cos[\[Omega] T[0]] Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1][T[1]]+Sin[\[Omega] T[0]] Subscript[\[ConstantC], 2][T[1]]
```

If I do

```
f = (x[0]/.sol[[1]][[1]])
```

I get

```
Function[{T[0],T[1]},Cos[\[Omega] T[0]] Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1][T[1]]+Sin[\[Omega] T[0]] Subscript[\[ConstantC], 2][T[1]]]
```

Which is close, but it has that "Function" function, and I just want the expression. So I try to do:

```
f[T[0],T[1]]
```

But this does not work, instead of the simple expression I want, it returns

```
Function[{T[0],T[1]},Cos[\[Omega] T[0]] Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1][T[1]]+Sin[\[Omega] T[0]] Subscript[\[ConstantC], 2][T[1]]][T[0],T[1]]
```

So my last question is how I simplify the above. Note that even though I'm giving a very simple example here, the real example is more complicated and features a dynamics that depends on both `T[0]` and `T[1]`. Also, this is based on code that I did not write, so I would prefer a solution that did not require re-writing the dynamics and such, ideally I would just convert that last Function into just the expression inside it. I hope this makes sense.

EDIT:
I forgot to add that this notebook was originally written for an older version of Mathematica. [Here is a link for this notebook.](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/2380/)

I did not notice initially, and I thank Michael E2 for bringing this up, but there is an error when I run the very first command. The error reads:
[image: Paramter specification {T[0], T[1]} in Function(...) should be a symbol or a list of symbols.]

I suppose it is "against the rules" to use as variables in DSolve indexed quantities like `T[0]` and `T[1]`. I suppose this was considered correct in the version of Mathematica that this script was originally written for. I would appreciate it if anyone could confirm this for me, after which I will mark this as "solved".

The stack trace for the error is:

```
{\!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"Message", "[", 
RowBox[{
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"Function", "::", "flpar"}], "MessageName"], ",", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}]}], "}"}],
HoldForm], ",", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"Function", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}]}], "}"}], ",", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Cos", "[", 
RowBox[{"\[Omega]", " ", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}]}], "]"}], " ", 
RowBox[{
TemplateBox[{"1"},
"C"], "[", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}], "]"}]}], "+", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Sin", "[", 
RowBox[{"\[Omega]", " ", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}]}], "]"}], " ", 
RowBox[{
TemplateBox[{"2"},
"C"], "[", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}], "]"}]}]}]}], "]"}],
HoldForm]}], "]"}],
HoldForm]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"Function", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}]}], "}"}], ",", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Cos", "[", 
RowBox[{"\[Omega]", " ", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}]}], "]"}], " ", 
RowBox[{
TemplateBox[{"1"},
"C"], "[", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}], "]"}]}], "+", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Sin", "[", 
RowBox[{"\[Omega]", " ", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}]}], "]"}], " ", 
RowBox[{
TemplateBox[{"2"},
"C"], "[", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}], "]"}]}]}]}], "]"}],
HoldForm]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"x", "[", "0", "]"}], "\[Rule]", 
RowBox[{"Function", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}]}], "}"}], ",", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Cos", "[", 
RowBox[{"\[Omega]", " ", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}]}], "]"}], " ", 
RowBox[{
TemplateBox[{"1"},
"C"], "[", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}], "]"}]}], "+", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Sin", "[", 
RowBox[{"\[Omega]", " ", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}]}], "]"}], " ", 
RowBox[{
TemplateBox[{"2"},
"C"], "[", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}], "]"}]}]}]}], "]"}]}],
HoldForm]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"x", "[", "0", "]"}], "\[Rule]", 
RowBox[{"Function", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}]}], "}"}], ",", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Cos", "[", 
RowBox[{"\[Omega]", " ", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}]}], "]"}], " ", 
RowBox[{
TemplateBox[{"1"},
"C"], "[", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}], "]"}]}], "+", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Sin", "[", 
RowBox[{"\[Omega]", " ", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}]}], "]"}], " ", 
RowBox[{
TemplateBox[{"2"},
"C"], "[", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}], "]"}]}]}]}], "]"}]}], "}"}],
HoldForm]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"x", "[", "0", "]"}], "\[Rule]", 
RowBox[{"Function", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}]}], "}"}], ",", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Cos", "[", 
RowBox[{"\[Omega]", " ", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}]}], "]"}], " ", 
RowBox[{
TemplateBox[{"1"},
"C"], "[", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}], "]"}]}], "+", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Sin", "[", 
RowBox[{"\[Omega]", " ", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}]}], "]"}], " ", 
RowBox[{
TemplateBox[{"2"},
"C"], "[", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}], "]"}]}]}]}], "]"}]}], "}"}], "}"}],
HoldForm]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"DSolve", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{
SuperscriptBox["\[Omega]", "2"], " ", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"x", "[", "0", "]"}], "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}]}], "]"}]}], "+", 
RowBox[{
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{"x", "[", "0", "]"}], 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None], "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}]}], "]"}]}], "\[Equal]", "0"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"x", "[", "0", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}]}], "}"}]}], "]"}],
HoldForm]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"sol", "=", 
RowBox[{"DSolve", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{
SubscriptBox["\[PartialD]", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}]}]], 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"x", "[", "0", "]"}], "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}]}], "]"}]}], "+", 
RowBox[{
SuperscriptBox["\[Omega]", "2"], " ", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"x", "[", "0", "]"}], "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}]}], "]"}]}]}], "\[Equal]", "0"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"x", "[", "0", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"T", "[", "0", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"T", "[", "1", "]"}]}], "}"}]}], "]"}]}],
HoldForm]\)}
```

which looks like this in the window:
[image]

Comment: Try to simplify the PDE by writing it  without unnecessary indexed variables

Comment: `(List @@ Values@First@First@First@sol[[2]])[[2]]`

Comment: `f[t0_, t1_] = DSolveValue[D[x[0][t0, t1], t0, t0] + ω^2 x[0][t0, t1] == 0, x[0][t0, t1], {t0, t1}]` evaluates to `Cos[t0 ω] C[1][t1] + Sin[t0 ω] C[2][t1]`

Comment: "...in such a convoluted way?" -- A solution is a list of replacement rules, one rule for each variable. Some solvers return a single solution (e.g. the `Find*` family of solvers). Other solvers return a **solution set**, that is, a list of solutions. A list of solutions, when there is only one solution and one variable, looks like a replacement rule with double braces. Having a consistent structure for a solution set makes coding easier, once you figure out how to do it.

Comment: I get an error message from your code. Didn't you think that had something to do with your problem? Shouldn't your question be about that?

Comment: @DanielHuber The real notebook I am working with, which was not written by me, makes extensive use of indexed variables, if by indexed you mean things like x[0] and T[1], etc. Replacing all of them is a task I would prefer not to undertake, especially since I don't understand everything that is going on in that notebook. I was written for an older version of Mathematica if that helps

Comment: @Syed although I don't understand how it works, it does work, so I might use that as a temporary solution. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Looking at it now, I guess I shouldn't have made that comment about the output being convoluted, it just came of the frustration I was having with this. The replacement rule was not the issue for me, only the fact that it is inside a list inside another list. But I suppose there's a situation where that's necessary, and it's neither here nor there. Indeed there is an error. In the version of Mathematica I was using, it goes into a separate window that I did not notice. Here in 12.3 it appears in the main window. I will edit the question to show this.

Comment: To be fair, solutions looked convoluted to me, back when I was first using *Mma* and all I wanted was the numeric value. But there is a structure there that one appreciates more when programming than when just calculating. Probably why they added `*Value(s)` variants over the years. — Where error messages are printed is controlled by the system variable `$Messages`. You used to be able to set it to the execution notebook (stdout) or the "Messages" window in the preferences, but I can't find it in the V13 preferences dialog.